# Managing the OAuth2 Authorization Grant lifespan

Tags: oauth

I'm trying to find anything in the OAuth2 specs that relate to the lifespan of the Authorization Grant. There is mention of the Access Token expiring and needing to be refreshed/renewed but I didn't see anything about the Grant. My impression is that if there is a need to expire or revoke an Authorization Grant, this would be something that would have to be added to the Auth Server and is not really within the scope of the OAuth2 framework.

Am I correct in my understanding or have I overlooked something?  Is this even a valid use-case?

Answer (score 0):

RFC 6749 (The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework) [mentions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.5) that:

> Authorization codes MUST be short lived and single-use.

RFC 6819 (OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations) [provides more detailed description](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-3.4):

> Browser-based flows expose protocol parameters to potential attackers via URI query parameters (HTTP referrer), the browser cache, or log file entries, and could be replayed.  In order to reduce this threat, short-lived authorization "codes" are passed instead of tokens and exchanged for tokens over a more secure direct connection between the client and the authorization server.

However there is no exact information about grant token lifespan in RFCs. From my experience it may be a minute or several.